# I can't understand the idea of "degrees of freedom"

Tags: statistics

I´m an economics student doing an inferential statistics course.The last class  the teacher talk about "degrees of freedom" and he said that it is not very important to understand the idea behind, just that if we estimate one parameter we are losing 1 degree of freedom and so on.
But I would like to understand that idea, if someone could help me with that, or just send me a link where I could read about it. I would be very pleased.

Comment: It would be good to provide perhaps an example topic in your course, or an example problem; what have you looked up?

Comment: Please indicate which distributions with degrees of freedom you're interested in. That way, we can gauge how general a theory of DOFs is needed. For example, $\chi^2$ requires less explanation than Fisher-Snedecor.

Answer (score 1):

The term "degrees of freedom" is troublesome because it refers to different things depending on context. In disagreement with your teacher, I think it is important to understand this term if you're going to use it. The relationship between the number of parameters and the degrees of freedom isn't always as obvious as the relation your instructor has given.

See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) which provides a few examples of how "degrees of freedom" might refer to a bias-correction of a statistic, the rank of a certain matrix, and others. Additionally, I recommend you read [Ye 1998](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2669609) for a notion of degrees of freedom that generalizes beyond linear modelling.

Comment: I was going to say that DF in a linear system can be relatively easy, but non-linear gets complicated, and care is required, because apparently general conclusions come with important conditions attached - the links you have given go so much further and explain so much more. Thank you - I had not seen that before.

Answer (score -1):

Here is about the simplest example I can think of.
Suppose you have four observations $6, 1, 3, 2$ from a normal population and want to estimate the population mean $\mu$ by the sample mean $\bar X = \frac{12}{4} = 3$ and the population variance $\sigma^2$ by the sample variance
$S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^4 (X_i -\bar X)^2}{n-1}.$

In order to compute $S^2$ by hand, you might make
a table such as the one below: Where $\bar X = 3$ and the four columns
have values of $X_i, X_i - \bar X,$ and $(X_i-\bar X)^2.$

```
       obs   obs-mean  squared
       -----------------------
        6    6-3 =  3     9
        1    1-3 = -2     4
        3    3-3 =  0     0
        2    2-3 = -1     1
       ------ ----------------
Total  12       0        14
```

So that $S^2 = 14/3 =4.6667,$

Now suppose you take a picture of your table to
compare with a classmate. But the second line in
the table gets smudged and can't be read. Your
classmate can still use the table. The first
column is 6 + `smudge` + 3 + 2 = 12. So your classmate knows
that `smudge` must be 1. Similarly, the smudged
values in the last two columns must be -2 and 4.

Given the structure of the table to compute $S^2,$ only $n - 1 = 4 - 1 = 3$ of the lines with computations contain the
required information.

According to your teacher's discussion, we have used $\bar X$ to estimate one parameter $\mu,$ so we have "lost a degree of freedom" (for estimating $\sigma^2,$ making confidence intervals, and testing).

That is one reason the definition of $S^2$ has $n-1$
in the denominator.

Computations in R:

```
x = c(6, 1, 3, 2)
mean(x)
[1] 3
var(x)
[1] 4.666667
```

Then if you want a 95% confidence interval for $\mu$
based on data $6,1,3,2$ it is of the form
$$\bar X \pm t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},$$ where the
number $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025$ from the
upper tail of the (symmetrical) t -distribution
with degrees of freedom $\nu = n-1 = 4 - 1 = 3.$

You can find $t^* = 3.182$ on line $\nu = 3$ of a printed
table for Student's t distribution, or by using
software such as R;

```
qt(.975, 3)
[1] 3.182446
```

In R, the procedure `t.test` gives such a confidence
interval:  $(-0.4374,  6.4374),$ Also, note
`df = 3` and `t = 2.7775` in the output, where
$T = \frac{\bar X - 0}{S/\sqrt{n}},$ which you should
verify using a calculator.

```
t.test(x)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 2.7775, df = 3, p-value = 0.06914
alternative hypothesis: 
  true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4374349  6.4374349
sample estimates:
mean of x 
        3
```